# bash sort ignoring non-alpha characters

Tags: bash, ubuntu-9.10

I'm trying to extract a list of unique tags from a tagged-text file. Tags are delimited by angle brackets, and each tag name starts with a colon: `<:ttx>, <ol_2>` and so on.

I started by adding a line-break after each `>`, then tried `sort`. The results baffled me, until I realized that `sort` was ignoring the first two characters.

Is there a switch I need to add, or is my Bbuntu-flavoured bash going for `sort -d` without the option?

Comment: Well, the -d option is _designed_ to ignore non alpha characters. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: You should include the command, some sample input and output, and what you expected it to produce.

Comment: Whenever you see 'weird' behavior from sort the first thing to check is your locale settings and how they might influence things.

Comment: why `<ol_2>` doesn't start with a colon? Is `<ol_2>` a tag?

Answer (score 11):

use `LANG=C` to disable your locale => `sort` usually works better:

```
grep -o '<:[A-Za-z0-9]>' your-tagged-text-file | LANG=C sort
```